# How to search for only whole words in a Swift String

Tags: regex, swift

I have this NS search expression. *searchString* passes in a String which I would like to search for in the *baseString* and highlight. However at the moment if I search for the word '*I*' an '*i*' in the word 'h*i*de' for example appears highlighted.

I've seen that I can use `\b` to search for only whole words but I can't see where I add this into the expression. So that only whole words are highlighted.

Another example could be if my *baseString* contains 'His story is history' and I used *searchString* to so search for 'his' it will highlight *his*tory.

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString as! String,options: .caseInsensitive)

for match in regex.matches(in: baseString!, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (baseString?.characters.count)!)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
    attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I thought of a better solution than my previous answer so I updated it. The original answer will follow for anyone that prefers so.

```
"(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9]|^)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=[^A-Za-z0-9]|$)"
```

Breaking down this expression, `(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9]|^)` checks for any non-alphanumeric or start of line `^` before the word I want to match. `[A-Za-z0-9]+?` matches any alphanumeric characters and requires at least one matched by `+`. `(?=[^A-Za-z0-9]|$)` will check for another non-alphanumeric or end of line `$` after the word I matched. Therefore this expression will match any alphanumeric. To exclude numbers to match only alphabets simply remove `0-9` from the expression like

```
"(?<=[^A-Za-z]|^)[A-Za-z]+(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)"
```

For usage replace the center matching expression with the word to match like:

```
"(?<=[^A-Za-z]|^)\(searchString)(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)"
```

**Old Answer**

I tried using this before, it finds every string separated by whitespace. Should do what you need

```
"\\s[a-zA-Z1-9]*\\s"
```

Change [a-zA-Z1-9]* to match what you are searching for, in your case fit your original search string into it like

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\(searchString)\\s" ,options: .caseInsensitive)
```

As an added answer, `\\s` will include the whitespace before and after the word. I added a check to exclude the whitespace if it becomes more useful, the pattern is like:

```
"(?<=\\s)[A-Za-z0-9]*(?=\\s)"
```

similarly, replace `[A-Za-z0-9]*` which searches for all words with the search string you need.

Note, `(?<=\\s)` checks for whitespace before the word but does not include it, `(?=\\s)` checks for whitespace after, also not including it. This will work better in most scenarios compared to my original answer above since there is no extra whitespace.

Comment: Thank you @ben-ong but how do I add this to my code above?

Comment: By the way, you can refer to [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression) to read up more on using it in swift. It is a little different from the generic way like the double backslash for example. And \b matches backspace

Answer (score 8):

You can easily create a regex pattern from your `searchString`:

```
let baseString = "His story is history"
let searchString = "his" //This needs to be a single word
let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)

//Create a regex pattern matching with word boundaries
let searchPattern = "\\b"+NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: searchString)+"\\b"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchPattern, options: .caseInsensitive)

for match in regex.matches(in: baseString, range: NSRange(0..<baseString.utf16.count)) {
    attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
}
```

---

Some comments:

- Assuming `baseString` and `searchString` are non-Optional `String` in the code above, if not, make them so as soon as possible, before searching.
- Empty OptionSet is represented by `[]`, so `options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions()` in your code can be simplified as `option: []`, and it is the default value for `options:` parameter of `matches` method, which you have no need to specify.
- `NSRegularExpression` takes and returns ranges based on UTF-16 representation of String. You should not use `characters.count` to make `NSRange`, use `utf16.count` instead.
- The return type of `matches(in:range:)` is declared as `[NSTextCheckingResult]`, you have no need to cast it.